# Возникает ошибка: AttributeError: partially initialized module has no attribute

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я делаю бота для телеграм с помощью библиотеки aiogram.
У меня код выдает ошибку:

```
import client.callback as cb
from main_bot import bot

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'client.callback' has no attribute 'new_callback_func' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Я не знаю как ее решить, пробовал разные методы, искал что то подобное в интернете и не чего не смог сделать.

Файл - main_bot.py

```
import client.callback as cb

bot = Bot(TOKEN)

#Вызов функции
cb.new_callback_func(dp)
```

Файл - client.callback.py

```
from main_bot import bot

async def callback_main_inline(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
***

def new_callback_func(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_callback_query_handler(callback_main_inline)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему создав в отдельном файле экземпляр класса Bot, предварительно удалив его из основного файла и затем импортировал этот экземпляр класса в main_bot и callback. После этого циклический импорт устранился.